# smtp - every mail with timeout

Tags: c#, email, timeout

I don't have a clue any more, what I did wrong. 
I try to send an Email by Code. I am using C# with VS2010. 
Here is my code:

```
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("MyMail@MyDomain.de", "MyPass");
            smtpClient.Port = 465;
            smtpClient.Host = "smtp.strato.de";
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

            //Setting From , To and CC
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("MyMail@MyDomain.de ", "MyAdminsMail");
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("User@OtherDomain.de"));
            mail.Body = "test";
            mail.Subject = "E-mailtest";

            smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

Every time I get a timeout within the last Code line. I have got a working Internet connection. The Email Address works fine within Outlook (sent/receive). And the following Code:

```
           Sender.Send("smtp.strato.de");
```

return with a success with a RoundtripTime of 27.

what is the reason for failing?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: **Thank you Neel!!!** That is the answer! Though Strato itself gives following advice: _http://www.strato-faq.de/article/259/Die-STRATO-E-Mailserver.html_

Comment: pleasure @Tagamoga if you think its the ans then mark as answer because someone has downvoted my answer

Comment: and about the link sorry I cant understand the language @Tagamoga

Comment: Oh I voted already... the "English" article you can find here: _http://www.strato-faq.co.uk/article/259/Settings-for-the-most-important-email-programs.html_ *It is ridiculous*. In the English one the correct port is mentioned. In the German one not. that is disgusting! :-(

Comment: awh yes may be German document is not updated yet @Tagamoga :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make a try using port 587 and the reason you can see in below image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Apparently the ports for Strato and Gmail are right in the moment the same. But you cannot suppose that this will be so for ever...

Comment: yes but as you have sent this link http://www.strato-faq.co.uk/article/259/Settings-for-the-most-important-email-programs.html they have suggested the same about using 587 port :)